# Generate a sorted report in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to generate a **report** in **Access** that depends on a parameter.
Let's say my table looks something like this:

```
id    usr    password    last_seen    workplace
01    test1  12345       --           M
02    test2  12345       --           G
03    test3  12345       --           M
04    test4  12345       --           H
...   ...    ...         ...          ...
```

(this is not my table, but for now assume it is).
Now I want to make a report where you can type in: "M" and it shows a list of people living in "M" (same for "Z", "G" and any other town).

How can I do this? I'm pretty new to Access so I really don't have an idea.

**MS Access Version:** 2010

Comment: Which version of MS Access you are using!

Comment: I use MS Access 2010 right now, but I thought it's not too different from the others so I didn't mention it @Lucky

Comment: Add a parameter surrounded by Square braces. Pl. follow my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the report query in design mode and provide a `Where` clause. The output is something similar to this,

```
 Where WorkPlace = [WorkPlace]
```

Feel free to leave a message if you are encountering any issues.

Comment: Its gives me an Syntax Error, because it interpretes it like this: "[Where WorkPlace = [WorkPlace]]"

Comment: Can you tweak it further to look alike, Where WorkPlace = [WorkPlace]

Answer (score 0):

Open the report with a filter.

In VBA:

```vb
Dim strWorkplace As String

' strWorkplace = "M"
' or interactively
strWorkplace = InputBox("Enter workplace")
' Prevent SQL injection
strWorkplace = Replace(strWorkplace, "'", "''")

DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName", WhereCondition:="workplace = '" & strWorkplace & "'"
```

For a numeric parameter, leave out the single quotes.